# How to keep emacs from joining lines when pasting text into an ascii table cell?

Tags: table, newlines

I have this text :

```
helo domain.com 
250 OK 
mail from: <user@domain.com> 
250 OK 
rcpt to: <jim@widget.net>
```

That I'd like to paste into this table cell

```
 +-------------------------------+-----+
 |                               |     |
 |                               |     |
 |                               |     |
 |           PASTE HERE          |     |
 |                               |     |
 |                               |     |
 +-------------------------------+-----+
 |                               |     |
 +-------------------------------+-----+
 |                               |     |
 +-------------------------------+-----+
```

With a simple `M-w` and `C-y` I get this

```
+-------------------------------+-----+
|helo domain.com 250 OK mail    |     |
|from: <user@domain.com> 250 OK |     |
|rcpt to: <jim@widget.net>      |     |
|                               |     |
|                               |     |
|                               |     |
+-------------------------------+-----+
|                               |     |
+-------------------------------+-----+
|                               |     |
+-------------------------------+-----+
```

(joined lines) instead of this

```
+-------------------------------+-----+
|helo domain.com                |     |
|250 OK                         |     |
|mail from: <user@domain.com>   |     |
|250 OK                         |     |
|rcpt to: <jim@widget.net>      |     |
|                               |     |
+-------------------------------+-----+
|                               |     |
+-------------------------------+-----+
|                               |     |
+-------------------------------+-----+
```

(Newlines preserved)

Comment: Are you sure the original string had (real, hard) newlines? And when I try pasting things into a table.el table, the table is all messed up: what kind of table are you using?

Comment: M-x table-insert

Comment: That's what I did too. But the table gets messed up if I insert a block of text like the above (even though the newlines are preserved for me).